# Is an empty string valid base64 encoded data of zero bytes length?

Tags: base64

One of my colleges was telling me that the empty string is not a valid base64 encoded data string. I don't think this is true (he is too lazy to parse it), but after googling around a bit and even checking the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548) I have not found any documentation that **explicitly** states how to properly encode a blob of zero bytes length in base64.

*So, the question is:* Do you have a link to some official documentation that explicitly states how zero bytes should be encoded in base64?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [RFC 4648 Section 10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-10), Test Vectors,

```
BASE64("") = ""
```

I would assume the inverse must hold as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can test the inverse by executing the following command in the terminal `echo | base64 -d | od`. It will print 0000000, which corresponds to the terminator (\0) of the returned empty string.

Answer (score 10):

My thought on this is that there are two possible base64 values that an empty string could produce; either an empty string, or a string that consists entirely of pad characters ('===').  Any other valid base64 string contains information.  With the second case, we can apply the following rule from the RFC:

> If more than the allowed number of pad characters are found at the end
>   of the string, e.g., a base 64 string terminated with "===", the
>   excess pad characters could be ignored.

As they can be ignored, they can be dropped from the resultant encoded string without consequence, once again leaving us with an empty string as the base64 representation of an empty string.

Comment: I like your approach, instead of having an empty string I could have  equal signs. BTW I think it should be either four or one. Base64 encoded data should have a length divisible by four. But the feature you are relying on is about excess characters that should be ignored, so I could just say "=".

Comment: I tried using .net method Convert.FromBase64String("==="), but it fails with an exception. Using string.Empty works and returns an empty byte[].

Comment: Sounds like the spec doesn't *require* graceful handling of extra padding. I would consider it generally invalid.